# VBA Excel | loop through rows until blank, error when only 1 row

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to be able to count the number of Rows with values (except Row 1 which is the Header) and do something with the data in each row.

Code runs fine if there are multiple rows of data.

```
Dim startX, NumRows As Integer 

If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        NumRows = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.count       
        Range("A2").Select                                              ' Start from A2.
        
        For startX = 1 To NumRows
'Rest of codes
```

However if I only have 1 row of data, I get this error:

Runtime Error 6 "Overflow"

When Debugging:
xlDown is showing me -4121
numRow is showing 0
Row.Count becomes a really large number

How should I resolve this please?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: First of all, use `Long`, not `Integer`. Then see the first linked thread for how to correctly find the last row. Also, you need to repeat the type: `Dim startX as Long, NumRows As Long`.